# How to detect the position of window in vim

Tags: vim, winmerge

I am trying to customize the mappings for vimdiff and make them similar to winmerge

In a vertical 2 way split, I want to map alt-left `<a-left>` to move current diff to left side and alt-right `<a-right>` to move current diff to right side.

For merging i can use `:diffg` and `:diffp`. But I need to know which split i am in so that i can use `:diffg/:diffp` in that.

Is there any way by which i can detect which split i am in.
Specifically is there is any way by which i can know whether the cursor is in left split or right split

`Related Question`
[how-to-get-list-of-files-which-are-currently-being-diffed-in-vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486420/how-to-get-list-of-files-which-are-currently-being-diffed-in-vim)

Comment: I like the question, although i recommend trying to not use the arrows. Part of what's so nice about Vim is that you don't have to move your hands! : )  Using something like alt together with < and > for left and right would kick arse! (Although it wouldn't make sense if you have your diffs horizontally, but i rarely do).

Comment: i am using `<alt-left>` and `<alt-right>` because i have also mapped `<alt-up>` and `<alt-down>` to move to next or prev diff. This just makes things more intutive.

As i already said i am doing this because vim doesnt come naturally to me , i m more used to wokring with and IDE like eclipe/visual studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are only two windows, the `winnr()` function will return `1` for the first window and `2` for the second window. You can also use `winnr('$')` to find out how many windows there are: `:echo winnr('$')`.

You can also just use `dp` and `do`, then you don't need to jump betweem windows as much, and it's easier to reach than the arrow keys.

Comment: dp do may be easy, but it doesn't come naturally to me. I have been forced on to vim from IDE world, but now i am trying to make vim map to what i used in IDE. This exercise has made me learn much more about vim than just commands

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your specific question, but here are some nice diff tweaks that might help.

```
"" Diff options; ignore whitespace.
set diffopt+=iwhite
```

I don't like the :diffon :diffoff because they mess with word wrap (turns it on when exiting diff). So i only set diff, scrollbind, foldmarker and foldcolumn.

```
"" Diff 'd' {{{
    nmap <silent> ,dd :set diff scb fdm=diff fdc=2<CR>
    nmap <silent> ,dD :windo :set diff scb fdm=diff fdc=2<CR>
    nmap <silent> ,do :set nodiff noscb fdm=manual fdc=0<CR>
    nmap <silent> ,dO :windo :set nodiff noscb fdm=manual fdc=0<CR>
    "nmap <silent> ,dd :diffthis<CR>
    "nmap <silent> ,dD :windo :diffthis<CR>
    "nmap <silent> ,do :diffoff<CR>
    "nmap <silent> ,dO :windo :diffoff<CR>
    nmap <silent> ,du :diffupdate<CR>
"" }}}
```

Also, check out the DirDiff plugin for diffing directory trees if you haven't already...