# How to get list of files which are currently being diffed in vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am writing a vim plugin in which i need to determine all those files which are currently being diffed. That is the ones for which `diff` is set. I have been going through the manual but could not find much.

Is it possible to do this.

This question is actually related to question [how-to-detect-the-position-of-window-in-vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473678/how-to-detect-the-position-of-window-in-vim).
In that question i was trying to get the position of window, so as to detect which one of the diffs is the right one and which is left one. The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473678/how-to-detect-the-position-of-window-in-vim/2474745#2474745) i got was to use winnr()

That solution can work only if there are only 2 windows(the ones being diffed). I want to make it generic so that even if multiple windows are open in vim, i can determine which one is on left and which one is right.
This is what i was thinking to solve the problem

1. Get a list of all listed buffers
2. For each of this buffers determine if `diff` is `1` for that
3. If `diff` is `1` use `bufwinnr()` to gets it window number.
4. From the window numbers determine which one is left and which one is right. left one will have smaller window number
5. And then determine if current buffer(in which `alt-left``alt-right` is pressed) is left or right using winnr of current buffer.

Now the pieces that are missing are 1 and 2. For 1 ls can be used but i need to parse its output. Is there a straightfwd way to get list of all listed buffers. And then is there a way to check if for that buffer `diff` is 1 or not.

Any suggestions for a simpler solution are also appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Cycle through all possible buffer numbers from `0` to `bufnr('$')` and check, whether this buffer exists using `bufexists(nr)`.
2. Save current buffer number using `let curbuf=bufnr('%')`.
3. For each existing buffer do `execute "buffer ".bufnumber` and check `&diff` variable. Remember two numbers, but do not check `bufwinnr()`.
4. Do `execute "buffer ".curbuf`.
5. Finally call `bufwinnr(nr)` for two numbers found in step 3.

UPD: another solution

```
let g:wlist={"0": [], "1":[]}
windo call add(g:wlist[&diff], bufnr('%'))
let g:diffbuffers=g:wlist.1
" here you have list of buffers with &diff option set in g:diffbuffers
```